# Having MYSQL Syntax error in PHP when using multiple AND

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL code

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM images WHERE 
(artist LIKE "'.$artistsearch.'%") 
AND (code LIKE "'.$idsearch.'%") 
AND (name LIKE "'.$namesearch.'%") 
AND (price BETWEEN '.$minprice.' AND '.$maxprice.')';
```

And I get the error

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'AND )' at line 5

However, running the code

```
SELECT * 
FROM images WHERE artist LIKE '%' 
AND code LIKE '%' 
AND name LIKE '%' 
AND price BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
```

Works fine in MySQL.

I've tried switching around ' and " and it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Just print out the value of the `$sql` variable and see what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's giving you the error? The error message suggests that your SQL includes `AND )`, and that string doesn't appear in that code

Comment: One of your php variables has value = "".

Comment: @andrewsi - it does if `$maxprice` is empty

Comment: @MarkBaker - ah, of course - I saw the quotes around it and thought they were part of the SQL, rather than the PHP string. Well spotted!

Comment: The MySQL code you just showed us does not even contain brackets so therefore it _cannot_ be the printout of `$sql`

Comment: The variable appears to be empty

Answer (score 2):

The error says the everything the problem in the last line

```
AND (price BETWEEN '.$minprice.' AND '.$maxprice.')';
```

as you can see "AND $maxprice )" part is the problem. Check the **$maxprice** and be sure it is not empty

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($maxprice)) {
   $maxprice = "some_default_number";
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM images WHERE 
   (artist LIKE "'.$artistsearch.'%") 
   AND (code LIKE "'.$idsearch.'%") 
   AND (name LIKE "'.$namesearch.'%") 
   AND (price BETWEEN '.$minprice.' AND '.$maxprice.')';
```